# Key detection does not work while in-game

Tags: vb.net, key

I am making a cheat, which can really be used in any game. I have a problem. I am using this to detect when did the user press the hotkey:

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Short
```

in combination with:

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(bind))) Then
```

It works perfectly while I am in Windows, but turns out when I start the game, it does not detect key presses at all.

How could I fix that?

Comment: `Short` is not (and never were) a `Boolean`. Better be a professional and set the strict compiler option `on` asap.

Comment: I am sorry could you explain it a bit more detailed what do I have to do, kind of new to this part of VB.NET.

Comment: Read the section *"To set Option Strict in the IDE"*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: Ok, but what am I supposed to do then, since I get the error: Error 1 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Short' to 'Boolean'. On both of my GetAsyncKeyState?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to evaluate. Here's an example using the inequality operator: `If (GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(bind)) <> 0S) Then`

Comment: Is this going to fix my problem?

Comment: I don't know. You've failed to include the expected and actual result. Nor do I see any attempt to extract the most/least significant bit from the result where the key state is stored.

Comment: Nop, I just tested it and it does not work.

Comment: And the result return from `GetAsyncKeyState` is...? What is the value of `bind`?

Comment: I have a label that is setup to say are you currently pressing the key, bind is set from a txt box which has 72 in it(any keycode works in windows), which is G, it works in windows but soon as I start the game, nothing `GetAsyncKeyState` does not detect anything and the label does not change!

Comment: Should I use a diffrent way to detect key presses or what?

Comment: An alternative is to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `True` and handle `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`.

Comment: Yes but does that detect key presses when I am not focused/I am focused in a diffrend app or it is minimized?

Comment: Okay. No, this will not work if the window is deactivated. Global keyboard hook is well documented. Here's a CP article: [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Comment: I already knew for keyboard hook, but I did not use it because it is complicated. How do I use it in my case? I really can't get a good understanding. I want to know when a key goes down and goes up.

Comment: You say *"It works perfectly while I am in windows"*. On what platform do you run the game? Xbox?

Comment: I meant while I am inside of windows enviroment it works, for example in the web browser, but when I go in-game nothing happens...